# How to force yaourt to install all updates

Tags: manjaro, aur, yaourt

I'm trying to update my system via yaourt, but I'm getting an error due to a python package installed with pip instead of yaourt.

I'm not succeeding in forcing yaourt to install the update, and I'd like to avoid to remove the package with pip and reinstall it with yaourt.

These are the commands I tried :

```
yaourt -Syu --aur
yaourt -Suya
yaourt -Susya --force
```

This is the output I get all the times :

```
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(39/39) checking keys in keyring                                                                                   [####################################################################] 100%
(39/39) checking package integrity                                                                                 [####################################################################] 100%
(39/39) loading package files                                                                                      [####################################################################] 100%
(39/39) checking for file conflicts                                                                                [####################################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
mutagen: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mutagen-1.36-py2.7.egg-info exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

How can I force yaourt to update the all packages?

Comment: `yaourt` is dead. Use `yay` instead

Answer (score 0):

At the end I just removed the package with pip, then reinstall it with yaourt.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you install something that overrides some file that already exists. You can check who is the package owner of that file with

```
pacman -Qqo /path/to/file
```

and then, if no one owns it, you can just delete that file and go ahead.

---

And yea, use `yay`, yaourt is dead.